# WPF: Programatically adding a ContextMenu to a DataGrid column header

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to add individualized and separate ContextMenus to each column header in my project, so that when a user right-clicks a header, a menu of checkboxes that relates to that header will appear that allows them to filter the data.

A couple of catches: the project that I'm working on needs to be developed for .NET 4.0, and as such I don't have access to the `DataGridColumnHeader` class that was introduced in .NET 4.5. Also, all of this needs to be done programatically, no XML allowed, as all of the column data is determined at runtime.

I found a [similar Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654959/how-to-add-a-right-click-context-menu-to-column-header-for-a-wpf-4-datagrid) in which this is done using XML, and I've sucessfully reproduced it in XML, but I'm new to WPF and haven't been able to reproduce it programatically.

I've pasted some C# code below where I think the setup should occur.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Function that adds all of the columns for the default setup
    /// </summary>
    public void MakeAllColumns()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < AllColumnDisplayNames.Length; i++)
        {
            DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn();
            col.Header = AllColumnDisplayNames[i];
            col.Binding = new Binding(AllColumnBindings[i]);
            canGrid.Columns.Add(col);

            // code for addding context menus will most likely go here


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGridColumns are not FrameworkElements so they do not have a ContextMenu. Since you want to do this all in code behind specifying a data template for the column can be a pain (IMHO). You could try passing in a FrameworkElement as the Header object for the column and set the context menu on that framework element.

Example:

```
//...

    DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn();

    //...

    TextBlock txt = new TextBlock() { Text = AllColumnDisplayNames[i] };
    txt.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(); // Build your context menu here.

    col.Header = txt;

    //...
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That added the functionality that I needed.