# WPF Datagrid: How to clear column sorting by mouse click on the column header?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, datagridcolumn, datagridcolumnheader

There're many answers about how to do this programmatically, but no one about via user interface.

Comment: AFAIK there's no built in way. So you'd need a button or a gesture or context menu or something as your user interface. Call the code out of one of those many answers from whichever  suits best.

Comment: yes, looks like adding popup for header is only way to go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654959/how-to-add-a-right-click-context-menu-to-column-header-for-a-wpf-4-datagrid

Comment: @Zam I think add a right click context menu on DataGrid may be more easier and simply

Answer (score 0):

The extended datagrid has three state sorting for columns.
As you click a header it cycles through down, up to no sort.
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wpfextendeddatagrid

Comment: But I'm using [Mahapps.Metro](https://mahapps.com/) for styling, is it compatible ?

Comment: I have never tried the combination, so I don't know.