# DataGrid context menu for complete column header

Tags: wpf, datagrid, contextmenu

How can I add a context menu to the *complete* column header? That’s including the blueish area in this picture:

[image: DataGrid]

Adding a context menu to the headers of single columns [already has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654959/how-to-add-a-right-click-context-menu-to-column-header-for-a-wpf-4-datagrid).

Comment: it is not very intuitive to add a context menu here... Maybe you should reconsider your choice to make your feature actually findable for the user.

Comment: @DenisSchaf If the context menu is on the complete header, isn’t this more findable?

Comment: Will this work for you  `<DataGrid ColumnWidth="*">`

Comment: @Martin i m sorry i thought you want the context menu only to be on the empty part

Comment: @Gopichandar No, but interesting approach.

Comment: ok i this case to fix the issue you can just extend the lengt of the location field to the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare ContextMenu to the entire DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ContextMenu="{StaticResource ColumnChooserMenuDataGrid}"
          PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="DataGrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp">
   ...
</DataGrid>
```

Write event handler:

```
private void Grid_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (VisualHelper.FindVisualParent<DataGridColumnHeader>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource) != null)
        return;
    if (VisualTreeHelper.HitTest((Visual)e.OriginalSource, e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender))?.VisualHit is DataGridHeaderBorder)
        return;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Where VisualHelper is:

```
public static class VisualHelper
{
    public static T FindVisualParent<T>(DependencyObject d) where T : class
    {
        while (d != null && !(d is T))
            d = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(d);
        return d as T;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but it works. However, if I understand this correctly, more work would be required if one wanted different context menus for column headers and somewhere else, e.g. data cells.

Comment: You are right. This is ready to use solution for the case where you need context menu only for headers area.